# list is not aligned vertically center in navbar in the flex

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am not new to flex but I am not able to vertically align the content of the navbar to the center in my code.

```
 <nav className="nav navbar">
        <h3> Logo </h3>
        <ul className= "nav-link1">
            <li className="nav-item1 ">
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item1 ">
                <Link to="/button">Button</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item1 ">
                <Link to="/text">Text</Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

and my CSS is:

```
.nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background: rgb(250, 172, 3);
  color: aliceblue;
}

.nav-link1{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

and I also have bootstrap imported into the project.

Any help would be appreciated !!! Thank you.

Comment: please add a working sample , use codesandbox or so

Comment: There might be some other css affecting this, it works fine for me. Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sheikhawais/6wngj3ka/5/

Answer (score 1):

Replace `class` with `className` if using `react`.

```css
.nav{
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background: rgb(250, 172, 3);
  color: aliceblue;
}

.nav-link1{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="nav">
        <h3> Logo </h3>
        <ul class= "nav-link1">
            <li class="nav-item1 ">
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item1 ">
                <Link to="/button">Button</Link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item1 ">
                <Link to="/text">Text</Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap, there is a padding-bottom given to the ul element.
Add `margin-bottom: 0` to your `.nav-link1` class and it will be aligned vertically.